# Github and local rep differs on file structure

Tags: git, laravel, github

I have a github Repository:

https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments/

When I browse it online, with

https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments/tree/develop/src

I can see there is 2 folders :

Models ( 3 files )

- DirectEliminationFight.php
- Fighter.php
- PreliminaryFight.php

models ( 11 files )

- Category.php
- Championship.php
- ChampionshipSettings.php
- Competitor.php
- Fight.php
- FighterGroupCompetitor.php
- FighterGroupTeam.php
- FightersGroup.php
- Team.php
- Tournament.php
- Venue.php

But this is not what I have in my local rep, I just have 1 folder:

- Category.php
- Championship.php
- ChampionshipSettings.php
- Competitor.php
- Fight.php
- Fighter.php
- FighterGroupCompetitor.php
- FighterGroupTeam.php
- FightersGroup.php
- PreliminaryFight.php
- SingleEliminationFight.php
- Team.php
- Tournament.php
- Venue.php

When I try a `git status` in my local rep, it tells me nothing about it.

Also, I use the package for a project of mine, so I can tell it works.

When I go to check the installed files, files are OK, there is not such difference.

So basically, the only view that fails is the Github one, is it a Github bug? I tried several branches, and it is the same.

The weird stuff is that it says I committed `Models` 8 days ago, and `model` 11 hours ago, so, it seems I commited both, but...

Anyone understand what happens?

Comment: It sounds like your local machine's file system is case insensitive, whereas Github's file system is case sensitive (I assume). Your filesystem is treating both folders as the same one, but Github is seeing them as two separate. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Mac os x . Files still don't t match...

Comment: I think that will be the case then. I have just cloned your repository on my Homestead box (Which runs Ubuntu and is case sensitive) and I can see that there are two folders `models` and `Models`. If you like I can move the classes in the `models` folder into the `Models` one and submit a pull request?

Comment: Thanks for the PR! Can you please make your PR in a new branch, instead of master? I need to test it first to see there will not break the plugin

Comment: Sure, I've created a new branch and a new PR.

Comment: Ok, I have merged the PR, and it seems so far that the plugin didn't break! You should write your solution as answer so I can accept it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, I'll write an answer for people landing here in the future. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue here is the case-sensitivity on the two filesystems. The OP's case-insensitive filesystem (Running on Mac OS X) and Github's case-sensitive file system. This could potentially cause the package to break when installed on a case-sensitive filesystem.

The solution in this case was to clone the repository on a case-sensitive filesystem (In this case a Laravel Homestead box running Ubuntu) and move the files from the `models` folder to the `Models` folder and then submit a pull request. This seems to have fixed the issue.